# Filter values based on multiple parameters in SQL (multiples rows)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Thanks for helping! I'm a newbie in SQL.

I trying to retrieve users for whom the value of column **`offers__c`** is equal to `'a'` but can also be equal to `'a'` and `'w'` and / or `'x'` and / or `'y'` and / or `'z'` and / or **empty** (`''`).

Each user can have multiple rows (with `'a'`, `'w'`, `'x'`, `'y'`, `'z'`, `''`) with a non-unique common id. (They must have `'a'` anyway.)
I would like to retrieve the rows if they exist, but no others.

For example: if a user has multiples rows with a column equal to `'a'` and (an other row with) `'w'` and (an other row with) `'p'`, I do not want to retrieve it.

```
SELECT  customerAccount__c, 
        offers__c,
        Id
FROM Table1
WHERE customerAccount__c IN (
    SELECT customerAccount__c
    FROM Table1
    WHERE offers__c = 'a' OR ( offers__c = 'a' AND (
            offers__c = 'w' 
            OR offers__c = 'x' 
            OR offers__c = 'y'
            OR offers__c = 'z'
            OR offers__c = ''
            )
        )
)
```

With this query I also get value like `'p'` or `'r'`. I would like to exclude other values that do not match the one's I requested.

**EDIT:**

**Table1:**

```
customerAccount__c    offers__c         Id
        -                 -              -
        1                'a'        0015800001RzCebAAF
        1                'w'            ...
        1                'x'       
        3                'y'
        2                'a'
        2                'w'
        3                'z'
        3                'a'
        4                'a'
        5                'a'
        5                'w'
        5                'p'
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
customerAccount__c    offers__c         Id
        -                 -              -
        1                'a'      a0G5808300xWGxQEAG
        1                'w'      a0G5737300xWGxqEAG
        1                'x'      a0G5809990xWGxqEAG
        2                'a'            ...
        2                'w'
        3                'y'
        3                'z'
        3                'a'  
        4                'a'   
        5                'a'      0015800001RzCCbAAF
        5                'w'      0015800002RzDAbAAF
        5                'p'      0015800003REDEbAAF
```

For this exemple, I get `offers__c` (5) with `'p'`. But I don't want it. I would like only the `customerAccount__c` (1) and exclude the (5) because of `'p'`.

:note that I do not know all the different values in the table (because there is like 130+ potential values) eg. `'p'`, `'r'`, `'g'` etc..

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
customerAccount__c    offers__c         Id
        -                 -              -
        1                'a'      
        1                'w'      
        1                'x'      
        2                'a'            ...
        2                'w'
        3                'y'
        3                'z'
        3                'a'  
        4                'a'
```

Comment: `offers__c = 'a' OR ( offers__c = 'a' AND ( ...` is redundant. `a OR (a AND (b OR c OR d OR e))` is equivalent to `a`.

Comment: Mind giving us table structure with data sample and expected output ? Otherwise, we can't do tests

Comment: pondia share sample data and output

Comment: With your query you are going to get all rows where offers__c = a, the other bit after AND is irrelevant. I'm not sure how orders__c can be both 'a' and 'w', it can't be both. You need to clarify your question a bit, share your table structure, some sample data and what the expected output to be.

Comment: I add sample data and output, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description is a bit unclear, but it sounds like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 AS t
WHERE EXISTS
         (SELECT 1 FROM table1 AS t1
          WHERE t.customerAccount__c = t1.customerAccount__c
            AND t1.offers__c = 'a')
  AND NOT EXISTS
         (SELECT 1 FROM table1 AS t2
          WHERE t.customerAccount__c = t2.customerAccount__c
            AND t2.offers__c NOT IN ('a', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', ''));
```

To explain a bit, this selects all rows from the table that satisfy two conditions:

1. there is a row with the same `customerAccount__c` that has `offers__c = 'a'`
2. there is no row with the same `customerAccount__c` that has an `offers__c` different from `'a'`, `'w'`, `'x'`, `'y'`, `'z'` and `''`

Comment: I follow you on Github right now! O.M.G your answer is exactly what I need. Thanks you sooo much for your help. I'm so grateful 

Comment: ``` 
AND NOT EXISTS
         (SELECT 1 FROM table1 AS t2
          WHERE t.customerAccount__c = t2.customerAccount__c
            AND t2.offers__c NOT IN ('a', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', ''));
```
This part mean : exclude 'a', 'w', 'x' .. right ?

Sorry for asking, I'm really a newbie in postgresql

Comment: It means "and there does not exist anything (any row) in the table where the `customerAccount__c` is the same and it has an `offers__c` with a bad value".

Comment: Oh I see now. Thanks you ❤️